# NSFetchedResultsController and array. Insertion

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a strange behaviour of NSFetchedResultsController. 
I want to use it with my array(not tableView). I mean, my array should contains list of objects from NSFetcherResultsController.

I create my list:

```
 _ = try? controller.performFetch()
 var myList = controller.fetchedObjects?.map { MyModel($0) }
```

And it works. But I have problems when I should update myList when `NSFetchedResultsController` updated. So, I have this method:

```
 func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        myList.insert(anObject, atIndex: newIndexPath!.row)
    case .Delete: ...
```

And I get crash on this line. For example, if myList contains 40 elements, and 20 elements should be inserted, then `newIndexPath` can be equal 53, but not 41. I mean, order of inserting incorrect (maybe it's bug of `NSFetchedResultsController`). I mean, instead of inserting objects of order 41,42,43,44,45,46 and so on, `NSFetchedResultsController` inserts objects something like this: 53,56,42,58,43,46,44 and so on.
With tableView it is working because when `didChangeObject` method called, then `NSFetchedResultsController` contains new data already (60 elements). But how I can get mirror of `NSFetchedResultsController` elements?

Currently I see only one solution. I should store updates, and when "controllerDidChangeContent" method called, then I should sort updates by indexPath and update myList. But may be exist the better solution?

Comment: What's the benefit to use  `NSFetchedResultsController` **without** a table view? The main purpose is to drive the UI (table view) responding to changes of the `NSManagedMangedContext`

Comment: Do you have a requirement to keep the existing contents of `myList`, or can you just recreate the whole list?

Comment: I use my custom view with collection structure. Regarding recreation list - I can do it, but if I have a lot of elements, then it can take a long time

Comment: Recreating the whole list is wasteful when you can react to changes and update the list.

Answer (score 0):

I do not recommend using a `NSFetchedResultsController` with anything other than a table view.  It is simply not designed for anything else.

You are **much** better off simply listening for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotifications` and reacting to them on your own.  You can easily implement your own context watcher (effectively the same core function as a `NSFetchedResultsController`) that will give you exactly what you need instead of trying to wrestle with the `NSFetchedResultsController` in a situation that it is not designed for.

There are plenty of examples on the net and I also discuss it in detail in my book on Core Data available from The Pragmatic Programmers :)

Comment: So, if I use iCarousel or some custom view with collection structure, I should create "custom" nsfetchedresultscontroller?

Comment: Building your own watcher of Core Data is trivial and expected behavior on iOS whenever you are building a custom UI.  I don't know about iCarousel or any other third party code, but if you build your own code it is trivial to monitor changes in Core Data and react to them.  NSFRC is more a demonstration than a final answer for all UI interaction.

Comment: It's not so trivial when you have complex predicate and sorting rules. If it is so trivial, why people not use 3rd party fetched controllers? :) if you like duplicate code, I don't. Nsfetchedresultscontroller has great features with cache and sorting. If you have your awesome fetched controller, please give me :)